# Creating JWT in Coldfusion for google Service account

Tags: coldfusion, jwt, google-oauth, cfml

I'm confused on the signature aspect for a JWT.  I believe I have the header and claim set correct as I got past any errors was seeing when originally writing this.  My question is mostly around the signature.  IS HMac with HMACSHA256 correct? I think I may be confused on where to get the private key for encryption.  If anyone has some guidance that would be great.

```
<cfset JWT_header = structNew()>
<cfset JWT_header['alg'] = 'RS256'>
<cfset JWT_header['typ'] = 'JWT'>
<cfset JWT_header = serializeJSON(JWT_header)>

<cfset JWT_claim_set = structNew()>
<cfset JWT_claim_set['iss'] = 'secret_iss'>
<cfset JWT_claim_set['scope'] = 'my_scope'>
<cfset JWT_claim_set['aud'] = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'>
<cfset JWT_claim_set['exp'] = 'Time_Stamp')>
<cfset JWT_claim_set['iat'] = 'Time_Stamp')>
<cfset JWT_claim_set = serializeJSON(JWT_claim_set)>

<cfset data = ToBase64(JWT_header) & '.' & ToBase64(JWT_claim_set)>

<cfset hashedData = HMac(data, 'my_secret_private_key','HMACSHA256')>

<cfset signature = toBase64(hashedData)>

<cfset JWT = data & '.' & signature>

<cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" method="post" result="result">
    <cfhttpparam name="grant_type"          type="formField" value="urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" />
    <cfhttpparam name="assertion"       type="formField" value="#JWT#" />
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>#result.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

This returns:

> '{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature." }'

Comment: Is there a public URL you're following for the signature structure? Also, there's probably a java lib for generating signatures. You might consider using that instead.

Comment: @Ageax The Documentation for Oauth 2.0 service accounts is here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority.  I could try the java sdk it's a good idea and I will look into it.  I would like to at least understand what I have wrong.  I like to understand why I have something wrong.

Comment: Two possible issues 1) `toBase64()` may work but is deprecated. (`binaryEncode` is recommended instead). If you actually do use toBase64, always specify the string encoding so CF handles it properly.  For that API, use "UTF-8". 2) HMAC returns a hex, so you can't convert it directly to base64 like this `toBase64(hashedData)`. Decode it binary first - then convert it to base64: `<cfset signature = binaryEncode(binaryDecode(hashedData, "hex"), "base64")>`

Comment: https://forgebox.io/view/jwt might save you some trouble!

Comment: @Ageax Do you have a link to where to see toBase64() is deprecated?  I see it in the Coldfusion 2018 documentation still.  Just trying to make sure it is.  Easy change on the project if so.

Comment: @UNOBerry - Yeah, it is still there, but if you look in the Usage section it says "Adobe recommends that you use the BinaryEncode function to convert binary data to Base64-encoded data in all *new* applications.". Any luck with the rest?

Comment: @Ageax I am working on it.  Other projects took priority.  It hasn't worked but I believe some of my issue was my understanding of the private key.  I am trying to make sure that is correct.

Comment: No worries. Ah, yeah a key difference would break things. That and #2 should fix things.

Comment: @Ageax So I got this to work without any issue in php.  I'm certain this is coldfusion with Sha256withRSA issue.  I can't find anything on replicating php's openssl_sign() to cfml anywhere.  This is driving me nuts.  I know it's the encryption.  Hmac vs RSA.  I have seen Ben Nadell's solution but he is starting with a pem file.  I am starting with json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with Ben Nadel's code(https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2941-experimenting-with-rsa-encrypted-signature-generation-and-verification-in-coldfusion.htm), but I had to modify it to work.  I commented out anything to do with a public key as I was not using one to interface with google.  If I was to enhance it I could create logic to look for the use of public or private key.  Next I skipped anything with Pem file formatting since google isn't using that.  Now it works.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that needs some code in the future to get them on the right path. This code is used for the firebase messaging api for push notification but can be adapted for other google services.

```
<cfscript>
variables.service_json = deserializeJSON(fileRead(expandPath('./serviceaccountprivatekey.json')));


variables.timestamp = dateDiff("s", CreateDate(1970,1,1), now());
variables.timestampUTC = timestamp + 21600; //add 6 hour to convert to utc 

//generate jwt 
variables.jwt_header = {
    'alg': 'RS256',
    'typ': 'JWT'
};
variables.jwt_header = serializeJSON(variables.jwt_header);
variables.jwt_header = toBase64(variables.jwt_header);

variables.jwt_claim = {
    'iss': service_json.client_email,
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging',
    'aud': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'iat': timestampUTC,
    'exp': (timestampUTC + 3600)    
};
variables.jwt_claim = serializeJSON(variables.jwt_claim);
variables.jwt_claim = toBase64(variables.jwt_claim);

variables.jwt = variables.jwt_header & '.' & variables.jwt_claim;


//sign jwt

variables.keyText = reReplace( service_json.private_key, "-----(BEGIN|END)[^\r\n]+", "", "all" );
variables.keyText = trim( keyText );

variables.privateKeySpec = createObject( "java", "java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec" )
    .init(binaryDecode( variables.keyText, "base64" ));

variables.privateKey = createObject( "java", "java.security.KeyFactory" )
    .getInstance( javaCast( "string", "RSA" ) )
    .generatePrivate( privateKeySpec );

variables.signer = createObject( "java", "java.security.Signature" )
    .getInstance( javaCast( "string", 'SHA256withRSA' ));

variables.signer.initSign( variables.privateKey );
variables.signer.update( charsetDecode( variables.jwt, "utf-8" ) );
variables.signedBytes = signer.sign();
variables.signedBase64 = toBase64(signedBytes);


variables.jwt_signed = variables.jwt & '.' & variables.signedBase64;

</cfscript>

<cfhttp 
    url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    method="POST"
    result="res"
>
    <cfhttpparam name="grant_type" type="formField" value="urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" />
    <cfhttpparam name="assertion" type="formField" value="#variables.jwt_signed#" />
</cfhttp>

<cfset variables.res = deserializeJSON(res.filecontent) />

<cfscript>
    variables.body = {
        "message": {
            "notification": {
                "title": "test",
                "body": "test test test"
            },
            "token": "e7blahblahSQ:thisisanexamplefirebasemessengingtokenpleaseputyourownonehere"
        }
    };
</cfscript>

<cfhttp url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/messages:send" method="post" result="res">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #variables.res.access_token#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(body)#" />
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#res.fileContent#">
```

Comment: "//add 6 hour to convert to utc " Don't forget about daylight savings time

Comment: Thanks so much for this. After hours of working with different JWT CFCs, all the pieces came together here to use Box's API. Slight modifications are necessary such as forcing the expiration date to be a string but this finally did the trick.